# How to convert DN to radiance in google earth engine for ASTER L1T Radiance

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm new in GEE and now I'm trying to convert ASTER L1T images from DN to radiance, for band B04, B05, and B3N. How can I do this?

```
var aster1 = ee.Image('ASTER/AST_L1T_003/20000507134140');
var gainRED1 = aster1.get('GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B04');
var gainRED2 = aster1.get('GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B05');
var gainRED3 = aster1.get('GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B3N');

var rad = function radiance(image) {
var rad_RED1 = aster1.select('B04').multiply(2.088);
var rad_RED2 = aster1.select('B05').multiply(2.088);
var rad_RED3 = aster1.select('B3N').multiply(2.088);
return image}
```

Comment: I played with ASTER some years back, and got a script that do this conversion. It also converts it to reflectance and masks snow, clouds, and shadows. https://code.earthengine.google.com/7542c7bfc66429f512251e4702c98b9f

Comment: @DanielWiell Thank you so much. Its help me to do radiance conversion!